# How can I dockerize a monorepo(built using turborepo) with hot reload enabled?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, monorepo, hot-reload, turborepo

This is a monorepo, web and api share the common packages that is the root directory and built using turborepo

I need to dockerize a `turborepo` with hot reload support. Dockerization is only for local development not for production. The repo uses `pnpm`.

I referred this but failed as this example in for yarn
https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/with-docker

This is the structure of root directory

```
├── apps
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docs
├── FUNDING.json
├── LICENSE
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── packages
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
├── prettier.config.js
├── script
└── turbo.json
```

This is the structure of apps directory

```
apps/
├── api
│   ├── dist
│   ├── Dockerfile (yet to create)
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── README.md
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile (yet to create)
    ├── next.config.js
    ├── next-env.d.ts
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── postcss.config.js
    ├── public
    ├── script
    ├── src
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
```

I referred this but failed as this example in for yarn
https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/with-docker

I have create a docker-compose.yml in the root directory

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:16.1-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    networks:
      - app_network

  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/web/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    networks:
      - app_network

  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/api/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
    external: true
```

Comment: How does "hot reload" work? `referred this but failed` how did you fail? Did you build the contains? Did they start? Did they exit with error? Does evrerything works except hot reload?

Comment: Hot reloading allows to see changes made to the code in real time without rebuilding the docker images each time. Mounting the volume of required code files directly into the container. 

I not sure how to write Dockerfile for such scenarios. As packages from the root directory is also required to run `pnpm dev`

Comment: One of Docker's core design principles is that a container _can't_ see files on the host, which makes it a poor match for hot-reload scenarios.  If you're not using Docker for deployment, why can't you just use plain Node?

Comment: I agree this is against the principle of containers. I would instead use docker for production. I am having a another issue

It would be great if you could help on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625163/internal-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-nonexistent

Answer (score 0):

For hot realoading for local development your write your dockerfiles normally. Then, for local development, typically have a separate dockerfile with mounted volume with the source code so you can edit it on host and changes come up into the container.

```
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/web/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - ./web:/where/you/copied/your/web/in/dockerfile:ro  # or not read-only, up to you
```

I would remove `app_network:`, docker-compose starts it's own network.