# Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/nonexistent'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, monorepo, turborepo

I have to dockerize a `turborepo` which has apps that include `api` and `web`

I have followed the below example
https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/with-docker

Dockerfile web

```
FROM node:18 AS base
RUN npm install turbo -g
RUN corepack enable

# This Dockerfile is copy-pasted into our main docs at /docs/handbook/deploying-with-docker.
# Make sure you update both files!

FROM base AS builder
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
# RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
# RUN apk update
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune web --docker

# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM base AS installer
# RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
# RUN apk update
WORKDIR /app

# First install the dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY --from=builder /app/out/pnpm-workspace.yaml ./pnpm-workspace.yaml
RUN pnpm install

# Build the project
COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json

# Uncomment and use build args to enable remote caching
# ARG TURBO_TEAM
# ENV TURBO_TEAM=$TURBO_TEAM

# ARG TURBO_TOKEN
# ENV TURBO_TOKEN=$TURBO_TOKEN

RUN pnpm prettier:fix
RUN turbo build --filter=web...

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
USER nextjs

COPY --from=installer /app/apps/web/next.config.js .
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/web/package.json .

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/.next/static ./apps/web/.next/static
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/public ./apps/web/public

USER nextjs

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

Dockerfile api

```
FROM node:18 AS base
RUN npm install turbo -g
RUN corepack enable

# The web Dockerfile is copy-pasted into our main docs at /docs/handbook/deploying-with-docker.
# Make sure you update this Dockerfile, the Dockerfile in the web workspace and copy that over to Dockerfile in the docs.

FROM base AS builder
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
# RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
# RUN apk update
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune api --docker

# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM base AS installer
# RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
# RUN apk update
WORKDIR /app

# First install dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY --from=builder /app/out/pnpm-workspace.yaml ./pnpm-workspace.yaml
RUN pnpm install

# Build the project and its dependencies
COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json

# Uncomment and use build args to enable remote caching
# ARG TURBO_TEAM
# ENV TURBO_TEAM=$TURBO_TEAM

# ARG TURBO_TOKEN
# ENV TURBO_TOKEN=$TURBO_TOKEN

RUN turbo build --filter=api...

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 expressjs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 expressjs
USER expressjs
COPY --from=installer --chown=expressjs:expressjs /app .

USER expressjs

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Attaching to api, web
api  | Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/nonexistent'
api  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/nonexistent'
api exited with code 1
web  | Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/nonexistent'
web  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/nonexistent'
web exited with code 1
```

Project Structure

```
├── apps
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docs
├── FUNDING.json
├── LICENSE
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── packages
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
├── prettier.config.js
├── script
└── turbo.json
```

```
apps/
├── api
│   ├── dist
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── README.md
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── next.config.js
    ├── next-env.d.ts
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── postcss.config.js
    ├── public
    ├── script
    ├── src
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
```

Comment: Hey, you'll probably want to add what your error logs and what you did to get to them. Ideally you'll have steps to reproduce.

Comment: Used this to build the images `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build`

And then 
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: EACCES: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: I tried this but this won't work in node runtime that is in docker